# Can an Exif IFD contain another Exif IFD?

Tags: tiff, exif

I'm writing an Exif/TIFF parser (in Java, but that's not really relevant to the question), and a user sent me a sample file that causes problems for my parser. It contains nested Exif IFDs. I.e. IFD0 contains an Exif tag, pointing to an Exif IFD, which again contains an Exif tag pointing to an Exif IFD, etc (4 levels deep, until the data seems corrupted with a > 2GB tag value).

Now, my question is, is this nesting of Exif tags allowed according to the Exif spec?

From my understanding of [Exif Version 2.2](https://www.exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF), the Exif (and GPS) tag is only allowed in top-level IFDs (IFD0, IFD1, etc). While the Interop tag is only allowed in the Exif IFD. Is this correct?